# Why is the Winterbash 2017 removed?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2017

I can't find the Winterbash 2017 icon on my account. Was Winterbash 2017 disabled? If so, why?

Comment: Any javascript errors in the console? Or did you click *I hate hats*?

Comment: Some of us are experiencing long load times which might or might not be related.

Comment: May I ask for the browser information?

Comment: for me its not there on IE but appears on chrome

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304366/is-winterbash-2017-disabled-for-internet-explorer-users

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is likely the same bug as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304370/295232); the Winter Bash system just didn't respond in time to queries (I've seen load times of more than a minute). That means it should be resolved now. If you use Internet Explorer, you are <s>using an inferior browser</s> [out of luck](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304368/295232).

Comment: No need for the strikethrough.

Comment: IE bashing is like Netscape bashing. It's outdated, historical. Edge is fine, also for winter bash.

Comment: Edge user detected.

Comment: Chrome user, but bash away if you like. ^.^ Do you do that with everybody who appears to be different than you? ;)

Comment: Maybe people shouldn't be offended by *everything* these days. Bashing IE is 1) fun which doesn't hurt anyone personally (except Microsoft maybe) and 2) simply a running gag.

Comment: *proposes to rename Winter Bash 2017 to Internet Explorer Bash 2017*

Comment: @LinusGeffarth you forgot 3) absolutely deserved for all those years we've had to make our websites IE-compatible.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth And just like almost every running gag ever, it's just not funny any more :)

Comment: Oh wow. Just realized all the bad puns potential of "Edge". So edgy. Careful not to cut you with all that edge, Windows users.

Comment: @GolezTrol Edge is not fine. It is full of useless proprietary features and a few years behind Chrome and Firefox in useful features that actually have W3C specs.

Comment: @DavidG Maybe it's not funny anymore _to you_ :)

Comment: @Paulpro In those ways, Edge is remarkably -- some might say suspiciously -- similar to how IE used to be. ;-)

Comment: @Paulpro FireFox is that browser that to be a bulky, unusably slow, memory hogging monster over the past 5 years? I heard it's better since this year's complete rewrite, but then again, since the old version is crap, I might as well not appreciate their efforts and just keep bashing it for fun. :p